# problem in Prestashop 1.6.1.10 "there is no product in this category"

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop, e-commerce

i have back-office prestashop version 1.6.1.10 
in the front-end of prestashop when i open a sub-category "prisems" show me that 
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0py1s.jpg) even if there is products in the category like you in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFL8D.jpg) there is product that already associated to the category "prisems"

Answer (score 0):

try clear cache and module block facettte off.

Regards